# minimum edges needed to connect the given pairs

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

We are given the number of vertices of a directed unweighted graph and a list of pairs of vertices like `(a, b)` . We want to make the graph in a way that there will be a directed paths between two vertices of each given pair. The problem is to find minimum number of edges to satisfy the conditions. Note that for every pair like `(a, b)` we have the below conditions:

1- `(a, b)` is different from `(b, a)`

2- if  `(a, b)` is in the given list, then there should be a directed path from `a` to `b` in graph.  This path may be multiple hop.

here is my try: as I found that hard to find an algorithm to find edges should be in the graph, I decided to add an edge between two vertices of each given pair in the graph (i.e. if the pairs `(a ,b)` and `(c, d)` are given, I draw two edges. One from `a` to `b` and the other from `c` to `d`) and then delete the edges which removing them does not affect connectivity between vertices. However I still could not find a way to indicate these edges.

Comment: A spanning tree will show you the edges that CANNOT be removed.  The rest, if any, can then be removed

Comment: @ravenspoint the graph will not necessarily be connected. So I can't find a spanning tree

Comment: " I decided to add edges between all given pairs in the graph "  So it will be connected!

Comment: @ravenspoint well. consider we have 4 vertices a, b, c, d and pairs (a,  b)  and (c, d). I just draw two edges here between a, b and c, d so it's not connected.

Comment: @ravenspoint  nope. all edges which I add at first are not necessary. consider we have pairs (a, b) ( b, c) (a, c). I draw three edges at first. But  obviously  I can remove the edge from a to c and still there is a path between all given pairs.

Comment: You are looking for a Steiner tree, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem, which is unsolved, usually NP-hard, but approximations exist in various research papers.

Answer (score 0):

> We are given the number of vertices of a directed unweighted graph

I will assume that this graph has some pre-existing edges to which you are going to add to and perhaps remove some.  You do not say this, but the question makes no sense unless there are such pre-existing edges.

Here is the algorithm ( pseudo code )

```
ADD edges between given node pairs
FIND maximal cliques https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem
LOOP over cliques
    FIND minimum spanning tree in clique  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree
    LOOP over edges in clique
        IF edge is NOT in spanning tree
            REMOVE edge
```

Comment: I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to implement code in java. I don't know any efficient way to find all cliques of the graph. is there any?

Comment: For the algorithm to find the maximal cliques in a graph  and a link to an efficient C++ implementation, please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68317177/16582